# Is there a europe-wide rule stopping under 18 year olds from staying in the dorms of hostels?

Tags: europe, accommodation, regulations, hostels, hostelworld

My friends and I are going inter railing and so will be staying in hostels across europe. One of the group will still be under 18 by the time we leave and several hostel sites have information saying that under 18 year olds have to book a private room as it is against the law to allow them to book a ned in a dorm. Is this rule strictly enforced in most places? And is it the same for the whole of the EU and europe?
Thanks

Comment: The EU is currently made up of 28 countries, and there's probably about a dozen more countries that are geographically Europe but not in the EU. Don't suppose you fancy being a little more specific?

Answer (score 8):

**No**, there is no "Europe-wide rule".  [HI](http://www.hihostels.com/web/a-faq.en.htm):

> **Do Age limits exist?**
>
> Youth Hostels are open to everyone. However age
>   limits may apply for children in some places - check with the Hostel.
>   Young people may be given priority when the hostel is nearly full.

Practices will vary from country to country and even hostel to hostel.  For example, in Finland [all ages are welcome](http://www.hihostels.fi/eng/info/faq.aspx), but at [Eurohostel Helsinki](http://www.eurohostel.eu/faq) under-18s travelling alone are required to present a letter from their parents with contact information.  In your case, since the rest of you are "adults", you shouldn't need even this (although it's probably a good idea anyway).